# VAT Rates of EU or better all Countries

Tags: data-request, economics, taxes

In this [Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_added_tax#EU_countries), there is a list of VAT rates ind EU countries and all other countries raising VAT. Is there a machine readable **open** source for such data?

I have checked dbpedia but they do not import tables yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can find this information in the [OECD Tax Database](http://www.oecd.org/tax/tax-policy/tax-database.htm#D_TaxesConsumption). The rates are provided in an [Excel sheet](http://www.oecd.org/ctp/consumption/Table-2.A2.1-VAT-GST-Rates-Dec-2014.xlsx).

Unfortunately the table is confined to 33 OECD member states, among which 21 are also member of the EU.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia tables are out of date in places. The official rates are at [VAT Rates Applied in the Member States  of the European Union](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/resources/documents/taxation/vat/how_vat_works/rates/vat_rates_en.pdf) (pdf).

It is unfortunately a PDF, with complex tables (although the first table of the main rates is simple enough to automatically extract).  A comma is used for the decimal point in the rates.

The tables after that show the wide variation in the way each rate applies in each country, and the geographic variations, which make a simple CSV quite hard to produce.

Comment: I know this PDF, that's why I asked for a "machine readable" source.

Comment: You can transfer these few PDF pages to a spreadsheet with 30 minutes of 'manual' labor.